# How to merge automation script with TFS

Tags: automated-testing, tfs

I have written automation script and I want to run it through TFS. Also I want results and proper status. When you execute the test cases manually in TFS, it briefs with proper status. How can the same be achieved for Automation?
I use Eclipse for Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using TFS and Eclipse, you will need to use the TFS plugin for Eclipse to link your automated test code with TFS test cases.

Once you've done that, you should be able to use that link to set up the reporting - exactly how  you do this will depend on your version of TFS and your environment.

If you are using TFS 2015 or later, or VS online, you should be able to set up a build and/or release task to run the automation through TFS, which will automatically post results to the test cases.

If you're using a different method, you may need to mess with the TFS API to have the results available when you view the test cases.